# iOS Application VIPER Architecture - how many dataManagers?

Tags: ios, architecture, viper-architecture

I am looking for an answer to this question in the context of the [VIPER Architectural pattern](https://www.objc.io/issues/13-architecture/viper/) -

If you have an application that talks to both a `web api` and a `database` how many `dataManagers` should you have one, two or three?

*Case*

**a)** `dataManager`

**b)** `APIDataManager` and `LocalDataManager`

**c)** `dataManager`, `APIDataManager` and `LocalDataManager`

*Where in*

**a)** The `interactor` talks to a single `dataManager` that talks to any services you may have (remote or local).

**b)** The `interactor` knows the difference between `local` and `remote` information - and calls either the `APIDataManager` or the `LocalDataManager`, which talk to remote and local services respectively.

**c)** The `interactor` only talks to a general `dataManager`, the general `dataManager` then talks to the `APIDataManager` and `LocalDataManager`

**EDIT**

There may be no definitive solution. But any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on where the abstraction lies within your app, that is distinguishing what you do from how you do it. Who is defining that there are two different data stores?

If local and remote data stores are part of the problem domain itself (e.g. sometimes the problem requires fetching remote data, and other times it requires fetching local data), it is sensible for the interactor to know about the two different data stores.

If the Interactor only cares about what data is requested, but it does not care about how the data is retrieved, it would make sense for a single data manager to make the determination of which data source to use.

There are two different roles at play here—the business designer, and the data designer. The interactor is responsible for satisfying the needs of the business designer, i.e. the business logic, problem domain, etc. The data layer is responsible for satisfying the needs of the data designer, i.e. the server team, IT team, database team, etc.

Who is likely to change where you look to retrieve data, the business designer, or the data designer? The answer to that question will guide you to which class owns that responsibility.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeff - I really appreciate the input.

Answer (score 5):

Neither VIPER nor The Clean Architecture dictate that there must be only one data manager for all interactors. The referenced VIPER article uses only one manager just as an example that the specific storage implementation is abstracted away.

The interactor objects implement the application-specific business rules. If what the app does is talk to the server, then turn around and talk to the local disk store, then it’s perfectly normal for an interactor to know about this. Even more, some of the interactors *have* to manage exactly this.

Don’t forget that the normal object composition rules apply to the interactors as well. For example, you start with one interactor that gets data from the server and saves it to the local store. If it gets too big, you can create two new interactors, one doing the fetching, another one—saving to the local store. Then your original interactor would contain these new ones and delegate all its work to them. If you follow the rules for defining the boundaries, when doing the extract class refactoring, you won’t event have to change the objects that work with the new composite interactor.

Also, note that in general it is suggested not to name objects with *manager* or *controller* endings because their roles become not exactly clear. You might name the interface that talks to the server something like `APIClient`, the one that abstracts your local storage—something like `EntityGateway` or `EntityRepository`.

Comment: Noted - thank you very much @eofster.